# DataSift anonymity - How can I target the authors of specific posts

Tags: datasift-python

DataSift makes users anonymous by creating a hash out of their user id. This makes it imposible to retrieve the user and be ale to target him.

If for example you are running a query meant at discovering negative tweets about your brand, is there any way you can target those users with specific advertising? Or is there any way you can connect to the authors of those posts?

Comment: That would kind of defeat the purpose of anonymising in the first place.

Comment: not really. I still can't get the identity of the author and be able to follow him. The only thing I can do is to show him an add. After all as a marketer this is the number one thing tou are concerned about

Comment: For example can you create something like UberVU with datasift?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the Twitter handle directly from the query data that DataSift provides.  In the returned interactions JSON, the Twitter user's handle can be found in two different places:

**interaction.author.username**

**twitter.user.screen_name**

See example below; look for the Twitter user @I_HATE_YOUR_BRAND:

```
{
...
    "interactions": [
        {
            "demographic": {"gender": "male"},
            "interaction": {
                "schema": {"version": 3},
                "source": "Twitter for iPhone",
                "author": {
                    "username": "I_HATE_YOUR_BRAND",
                    "name": "mr. hater mcgee",
                    "id": 39823492,
                    ...
                },
                "type": "twitter",
                ...
            },
            "twitter": {
                ...
                "user": {
                    "name": "mr. hater mcgee",
                    "location": "SoCal",
                    ...
                    "screen_name": "I_HATE_YOUR_BRAND",
                    ...
                }
            }
        },
        ...
```

Comment: @Ryan Was my answer not helpful?  Can you accept or at least give me an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to uncover the identity of Facebook users from DataSift's Facebook Public Source, this is not possible; this data source has been anonymised for privacy reasons.